# Using re.sub to replace a

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text. I want to remove certain words and phrases.

One sentence is: We lived there in the l[b]ate[/b] 1990s.

I search it to find **ate**. (= words[0])

newline = re.sub('ate', newselectionString, line)

But  I only want it to find **ate**, on its own, not as part of another word.

Is it possible to tell re just to find these 3 letters?

Later in the text is: The best thing was when we **ate** ice cream.

```
for line in lines:
        for i in range(0, len(words)):
            if words[i] in line:
                print('Found ' + words[i])
                newselectionString = selectionString.replace('GX', 'G' + str(startInt))
                newline = re.sub(words[i], newselectionString, line)
                newLines.append(newline)
                startInt +=1
```

Comment: use word boundaries --> `\bate\b`

Comment: And if I use newline = re.sub(words[i], newselectionString, line)?? How to set the boundaries? I get an error in my Python shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundaries `\b` with `str.format`.

**Ex:**

```
re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(words[i]), "Hello World", Text)
```

Comment: Great! Works like a dream! Thanks for helping an amateur out!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to do it:

### Regular Expression

The regex you want is `\bate\b`, or that `ate` should appear between two word boundaries. It will match `We ate.`, `I ate it.`, but not `We're late.`.

### Splitting the String

Fairly similar to just a normal regex, but you might want control over the other words in the sentence.

```py
word_fragments = re.split("\b", your_string)

print(' '.join([word for word in word_fragments if word != 'ate']))
```

Comment: thanks, thing is, I don't have a word, I have words[i] in a loop. How to do that?